# meteor facts package shows nothing, if I include facts-base I get "Ignoring duplicate publish"

Tags: javascript, meteor

I added the `facts` package to my Meteor app a long time ago, and it stopped working, the facts template simply shows nothing anymore. I heard the package was split in two and I should add `facts-base`.

This works, but I also get the message:

```
Ignoring duplicate publish named 'meteor_facts'
```

But when I remove the old `facts` package, I also don't seen the statistics anymore. How do I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the [changelog](https://docs.meteor.com/changelog.html#changes-18), I fixed it by replacing the original `facts` package by both `facts-base` and `facts-ui`.